# What is the meaning of "quotient of polynomials in $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\dots?$

Tags: terminology, extension-field

I'm reading Artin's "Galois Theory", here:

A. **Extension Fields.**
If $E$ is a field and $F$ a subset of $E$ which, under the operations of addition and multiplication in $E$, itself forms a field, that is, if $F$ is a subfield of $E$, then we shall call $E$ an **extension** of $F$. The relation of being an extension of $F$ will be briefly designated by $F\subset E$. If $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\dots$ are elements of $E$, then by $F(\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\dots)$ we shall mean the set of elements in $E$ which can be expressed as quotients of polynomials in $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\dots$ with coefficients in $F$. It is clear that $F(\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\dots)$ is a field and is the smallest extension of $F$ which contains the elements $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\dots$. We shall call $F(\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\dots)$ the field obtained after the **adjunction** of the elements $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\dots$ to $F$, or the field **generated** out of $F$ by the elements $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\dots$. In the sequel all fields will be assumed commutative.

What does he means by "quotient of polynomials in $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\dots?$

Comment: rational functions of $\alpha, \beta, \gamma...$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By "quotients of polynomials" Artin means *rational functions* of $\alpha,\beta,\gamma\dots$ like
$$\frac{c_1\alpha}{c_2\beta+c_3\gamma}$$
where the $c_i$ are elements of the smaller field $F$.